# React-motion rendering on every animation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, react-motion

I'm getting really bad performance using React-Motion (https://github.com/chenglou/react-motion). I'm animating the height of a dropdown from a table row from `0` to `260`.

```
constructor() {
    this.state = {
        opened: false
    }

    this.handleRowClick = this.handleRowClick.bind(this)
}

handleRowClick() {
    this.setState({
        opened: !this.state.opened
    })
}

render() {
    <Motion style={{height: spring(this.state.opened ? 260 : 0, {stiffness: 140, damping: 30})}}>
        {(height) => 
            <div onClick={this.handleRowClick}>
                <div style={height}>
                    ...stuff goes here
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </Motion>
}
```

The animation is working as expected, but upon logging the height every time it renders all of this in the span of ~5 seconds (which is WAY too long):
[image]

Maybe I misread something in the docs, but is there a way to avoid lag on the animation?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to apply the transition styles to a `div` and render a component inside it which implements `shouldComponentUpdate` (eg. with `React.PureComponent`) to prevent it from rerendering when not needed.

```
render () {
  <Motion 
    style={{
      height: spring(
        this.state.opened ? 260 : 0, 
        { stiffness: 140, damping: 30 }
      )
    }}
  >
    {(height) => 
      <div style={height}>
        <YourComponent />
      </div>
    }
  </Motion>
}
```

And `MyComponent` might be something like `class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent` or using a HOC like `pure` from [`recompose`](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose). This way `MyComponent` will only update when it's props changes.